# Unable to install Chromedriver on Centos 7

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, centos7, yum, dnf

Tried installing chromedriver on centos 7 got the following error but dnf and yum are unable to find the package. It should be available

First tried using dnf:
sudo dnf -y install chromedriver
cPanel Addons Production Feed                                                                                                 0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00
cPanel Plugins project                                                                                                        0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'cpanel-addons-production-feed', ignoring this repo.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'cpanel-plugins', ignoring this repo.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:23 ago on Thu 20 Apr 2023 05:54:41 PM UTC.
No match for argument: chromedriver
Error: Unable to find a match: chromedriver
Then tried with yum:
sudo yum -y install chromedriver
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

- EA4: 203.174.85.202
- cpanel-addons-production-feed: 203.174.85.202
- cpanel-plugins: 203.174.85.202
- base: repo.extreme-ix.org
- extras: repo.extreme-ix.org
- updates: repo.extreme-ix.org
  No package chromedriver available.
  Error: Nothing to do
  Can anyone help me install the package on my Centos server